# Insert php array into javascript

Tags: php

I got a script that:

- reads urls from a txt file
- does some calculations
- inserts results into a table

I want to replace txt file with php array. Heres my current code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $.get("imones.txt", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime(); 
        var loadTimes = []; 
            var beforeTimes = [];                           
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                             
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad); /
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());               
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.shift());  
                try {
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {                 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000; 
                        if (result < 0) { 
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }
                    $("#loadingtime" + [index]).html(result);                       
                    beforeLoad = value;             
                });
                } catch(ex) {}
        }).attr('src', array.shift()); 

</script>
```

It reads from imones.txt, then inserts each url into a frame, does some calculations, and then inserts results into `#loadingtime` div. I want to replace imones.txt with a php array. Also i would like the output to be stored in another php array instead of storing it in a div. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: by replacing imones.txt by a php array you mean replacing "imones.txt" with "imones.php" which contains a PHP array which value you want to retrieve?

Comment: No its just a `$array = array();` in the same file, it stores the same urls as imones.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php
    $str = implode(',',$yourPhpArr);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var urls = "<?=$str?>";

    var array = urls.split(/,/);
    var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime(); 
    var loadTimes = []; 
    var beforeTimes = [];

    $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                             
       beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad); /
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());               
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.shift());  
                try {
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {                 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000; 
                        if (result < 0) { 
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }
                    $("#loadingtime" + [index]).html(result);                       
                    beforeLoad = value;             
                });
                } catch(ex) {}
        }).attr('src', array.shift()); 

</script>
```

Comment: Depending on your configuration, <?=$str?> may not work. It that's the case use <?php echo $str ?> instead

Comment: You are right, but it really annoying when you insert lot of vars to php :)

I read somewhere what in next versions `<?=` will work like `<?php echo` for any configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Let a php file echo your array:

```
echo Array(1,2,3,4,5);
```

your html/javascript:

```
   $.get("yourphp.php", function (data) {
        var array = data.split(/\r\n|\r|\n/);
        var beforeLoad = (new Date()).getTime(); 
        var loadTimes = []; 
            var beforeTimes = [];                           
        $('#frame_id').on('load', function () {                                             
            beforeTimes.push(beforeLoad); /
            loadTimes.push((new Date()).getTime());               
            $('#frame_id').attr('src', array.shift());  
                try {
                $.each(loadTimes, function (index, value) {                 
                    var result = (value - beforeTimes[index]) / 1000; 
                        if (result < 0) { 
                            result = result * (-1);
                        }
                    $("#loadingtime" + [index]).html(result);                       
                    beforeLoad = value;             
                });
                } catch(ex) {}
        }).attr('src', array.shift()); 

</script>
```